# Modelling a pendulum with physical restrictions on it's range of motion

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

I'm currently working on a project based on suspension bridges and their oscillations. I've got an equation of motion for the movement of a pendulum as shown in the first image, I then wanted to be able to model for if the pendulum was physically restricted by something like a wall, and did some research into the [heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and formed an equation as shown again in the first image, limiting the value of theta to a maximum theta. This worked in that it did restrict the values of theta, but naturally a pendulum coming into contact with a wall would simply bounce back off and carry on with its movement rather than taking the same amount of time it would have done without the wall present to continue with its oscillations, as is implied in the graph in the second image. How could I take into account for this in my model and essentially "push together" the defined areas of my graph shown in the second image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the pendulum is not driven, you can probably do this with a lot of floor functions and step functions, but it would look pretty ugly. If it is driven irregularly, I think you should just go straight to numerics.